# Content is not showing from the specific page while using the react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I create an app having the following files, But my problem is that while using react-router-dom, The contents in pages like jobs.js, and home.js are not displaying. I reffered similar questions in stackoverflow, but none of them are working for me!

App.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App container">
      

      <nav className='navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-dark'>
        <ul className='navbar-nav'>
          <li className='nav-item m-1'>
            <NavLink className='btn btn-light btn-outline-primary' to="/home">
              Home
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li className='nav-item m-1'>
            <NavLink className='btn btn-light btn-outline-primary' to="/jobs">
              Jobs
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li className='nav-item m-1'>
            <NavLink className='btn btn-light btn-outline-primary' to="/jobdetails">
              Job Details
            </NavLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <Routes >
        <Route path='/home' element={<home/>} />
        <Route path='/jobs' component={jobs} />
        <Route path='/jobdetails' component={jobdetails} />
      </Routes >
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

jobs.js

```
import React,{Component} from "react";

export class jobs extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h3>This is Jobs Page</h3>
            </div>
            
        )
    }
}
```

home.js

```
import React,{Component} from "react";

export class home extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h3>This is Home Page</h3>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

[image: Output Image]

Comment: Keep the component name Pascal case - `Home` like so ...

Comment: Hey, @KcH Sorted the problem. Strictly it was related to pascal casing. Thanks for the answer! Continue helping.

Answer (score 0):

`component` prop was removed in version 6

Use `element` instead

```
<Route path='/home' element={<home/>} />
<Route path='/jobs' element={<jobs/>} />
<Route path='/jobdetails' element={<jobdetails/>} />
```

Comment: and Lin, they are in `home` tab so I feel the Pascal case thing 

Comment: import { Navigate, useRoutes } from "react-router-dom";
import { Jobs } from './Jobs';
import { JobDetails } from './JobDetails';
import { HOME } from "./Home";
const MainRoutes = () => {
  return useRoutes([
    {
      path: "/home",
      element: <HOME />,
    },
    {
      path: "/jobs",
      element: <Jobs />,
    },
    {
      path: "/jobdetails",
      element: <JobDetails />,
    },
  ]);
};
export default MainRoutes;

Comment: Please check useRoutes

Comment: https://devforhelp.com/code5/index.html you can check here it is working and if you need code then I will share via git

Comment: @devforhelp you could have just used codesandbox or other service

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-vaughan-ctztdw?file=/src/App.js